# Data binding not updating when property changes in Angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I can't figure out how to bind the fields to the component so that the fields update when i change the properties in OnDataUpdate().

The field "OtherValue" has a working two way binding to the input-field and the field for "Name" displayes "test" when the component is displayed. But when i refresh the data, none of the fields are updated to display the updated data.

The first logged value of "this.name" is undefined(???), the second is correct, but the field bound to the same property does not update.

How can the component provide the initial value for the name-field, but when the data update is trigged, the name-property is suddenly undefined?

stuff.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    selector: 'stuff',
    templateUrl: 'stuff.component.html'
})

export class StuffComponent {
    Name: string = "test";
    OtherValue: string;

    constructor(private dataservice: DataSeriesService) {
        dataservice.subscribe(this.OnDataUpdate);
    }

    OnDataUpdate(data: any) {
        console.log(this.Name);
        this.Name = data.name;
        this.OtherValue = data.otherValue;
        console.log(this.Name);
}
```

stuff.component.html

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Other</th>
        <td>{{OtherValue}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input [(ngModel)]="OtherValue" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `this` context is lost if you pass it like that in the `subscribe()` function. You can fix this in several ways:

*by using bind*

```
constructor(private dataservice: DataSeriesService) {
    dataservice.subscribe(this.OnDataUpdate.bind(this));
}
```

*by using an anonymous arrow function wrapper*

```
constructor(private dataservice: DataSeriesService) {
    dataservice.subscribe((data : any) => {
        this.OnDataUpdate(data);
    });
}
```

*change the declaration of the function*

```
OnDataUpdate = (data: any) : void => {
      console.log(this.Name);
      this.Name = data.name;
      this.OtherValue = data.otherValue;
      console.log(this.Name);
}
```

Comment: What if it's not a function invocation and is a value assignment?? @pierreduc

Comment: Then you should wrap that assignment in an anonymous arrow function

Answer (score 3):

Passing method references this way breaks the `this` reference

```
dataservice.subscribe(this.OnDataUpdate);
```

use this instead:

```
dataservice.subscribe((value) => this.OnDataUpdate(value));
```

By using [`()=>` (arrow function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `this` is retained and keeps referring to the current class instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing `this` context, to keep context you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
dataservice.subscribe(this.OnDataUpdate.bind(this));
```